# To use ajax or not - for many changes in the page

Tags: ajax, e-commerce

I am going through a requirement of an ecommerce checkout flow. One of the striking feature is the heavy use of ajax there. For example - there is a page where user can apply gift card. The requirement is to have this functionality in ajax, however - there are many elements in the page that would have to be refreshed once the gift card has been applied to the order (like - removing credit card if it was already there, refreshing total price etc...)  I personally feel this is an overkill of using ajax to update MANY portions of page, I rather do a page reload - this keeps the application simple and maintainable. Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: If it's a requirement, you must implement it, otherwise it's not a requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if it's a requirement, you might be stuck with using Ajax, but lets pick this apart any way because there are a few issues at play.

First, I'd focus on the user experience. Often times the immediate feedback of ajax-based updates are going to help the user understand what happened rather than have the full postback and possibly have them end up at the top of the form or otherwise lose focus on the element that they were editing.  If you have an automatic postback after an on_change event (or similar) then the user doesn't expect the refresh and can be frustrated.  If you want for a click (submit) event and then do all of the validations, the user can be hammered with a ton of errors and hate the experience.

Generally - immediate feedback is good.  I'd probably go ajax unless there is a good reason not to.

Another consideration is page load times and how many times you have to send data to/from the server to get the job done.  That overhead alone might make it worth using ajax.

Lastly - maintenance.  I don't know what framework you're using so I can't comment on that, but in ASP.NET, for example, it's very easy to implement ajax that updates part of a page.  I'd actually argue that maintaining this type of an event is easier than handling the entire postback and refresh each time.

Hope this helps give you a few ideas.